# z-index or focus issue with bootstrap dropdown

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to fix an annoying bug on this page - https://www.minimoda.bg/products/4/zimna-detska-pletena-roklq-rozova

The moment you select a size from the dropdown (the size is on the right side of the price) and you hover the picture on the left (item picture), the selected size will appear on top of the zoom preview.
[image]
However if after you select a size, you click somewhere on the page and then hover the picture - it will be ok. Like if there is some focus state that remains.

Any assistance is welcome as I spent hours trying to fix it without success.

Comment: We need a minimal, verifiable example of the code you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Bootstrap selector causing your problem...

```
.btn-group > .btn:focus { z-index: 2; }
```

Its being applied to this button...

```
<button type="button"
        class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default"
        data-toggle="dropdown"
        title="2-3 години (92-98 см)"
        aria-expanded="false">
  <span class="filter-option pull-left">2-3 години (92-98 см)</span>
  &nbsp;
  <span class="bs-caret">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </span>
</button>
```

Don't modify the Bootstrap selector.  Instead add a custom class to your button, like so...

```
<button ... class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default example" ...>
  ...
</button>
```

...and in your custom CSS set the `z-index` to `0` using the same selector, but with your custom class name included.  This will increase the specificity and override appropriately.

```
.btn-group > .btn.example:focus { z-index: 0; }
```

Comment: I wrapped the entire thing in a div and applied the css to it as I'm not sure how to add the custom class. This button is generated by BS itself. In any way thanks a lot for the solution.